# Best practices to prevent unneeded liquibase changesets in production

Tags: liquibase

So here is the scenario:

- release is pushed to production every 2 sprints
- dev is writing changesets during a sprint that add table A + 2 columns in table B, commits them, it gets pushed to QA, everything good.
- during sprint demo, stakeholder identifies that he needs 2 more fields in table B, and that a whole section needs to be reworked, leading to dropping table A, removing 3 columns in table B and adding 2 new  ones in table B
- next sprint, developer implements the changes identified in sprint demo (ie adding changesets to drop table that was previously added etc)

=> so now we have changesets that when they are deployed to production are basically going to create a table and then drop it right away. For minimal changes like above this is not really a problem, but for bigger changesets you could end up having the production database transaction log growing unnecessarily. The time to upgrade production might be increased also quite a bit because of those changesets that revert work that did not need to be done in the first place.

1. Would it be recommended to rework the changesets so that for a release only the required changesets are executed (basically reworking changesets of the 2 sprints)?
2. Alternatively would you have 2 sets of changesets (one for dev that accumulates all the changes made during the sprints, one for production that minimizes the amount of changes).
3. Is this all going against the "wrong is right" principle (page 17 of https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1U8vESZVbj-zFE-K1Vh5dVfiH8xns9Gv9zDzg0DZBcKc/edit?pli=1#slide=id.g119ea23dc_00)

Answer (score 2):

Creating separate changesets for production sort of defeats the whole purpose of tracking migrations.  That being said, if you're determined to go down this path, have a look at contexts.  You can tag certain changesets as those approved for production, and run your production migration selecting only for those tags.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually recommend is to just not worry about the unneeded changesSets. They may create a table and then drop it again, but the database is really fast at doing that.

Modifying the changeLog can avoid the production database making and dropping unnecessary objects, but in the process your dev databases can easily end up different than production due to changeSets that ran on them but not production. Furthermore, the testing you already did was against the original command flow and that may or may not work with the new and you want no surprises when you deploy to production.

The only time I recommend pulling out changeSets is for unnecessary expensive operations such as a createIndex followed by a dropIndex on a large table.